disable ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed errors in QWebEngineView
For this little example ,
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
# or
# from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets


class BetterWebView(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl())
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = BetterWebView()
    view.load(QtCore.QUrl("https://www.qt.io"))
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

after running it, I got a list of errors like
[12248:2260:0721/112136.109:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.110:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
js: While parsing speculation rules: A rule contains an unknown key: "eagerness".
[12248:2260:0721/112136.411:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.412:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.414:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.416:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.443:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.444:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.758:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112136.760:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112141.494:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112141.494:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112141.497:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[12248:2260:0721/112141.498:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107

They are not helpful in my case, I wonder how to suppress(not show) them?

Which specific versions of Qt6, QtWebEngine and PySide6 are you using, and on which platform? Do you see the same output when using PyQt?

@ekhumoro Python v3.12.0 PyQt6 v6.7.1 win11

Your example uses PySide6, not PyQt6. Which one has the problem? Also, did you see this output with earlier versions of Qt6? I tested your script on Linux using both PyQt-6.7.0 and PySide-6.7.2 with Qt-6.7.2, but I don't see any SSL errors. Those are coming from Chrome, so you could try filtering them out using e.g. QWebEnginePage.certificateError. The JS warnings can be filtered out using QWebEnginePage.javaScriptConsoleMessage.

@ekhumoro Thanks for help! I tested with PySide6 and PyQt6 on win11, both suffered   the issue. I have tried filtering them out using QWebEnginePage.certificateError, but no workable solution found.

It's possible to send chromium options to Qt's web-engine process by appending them to the main application command-line arguments (see Qt WebEngine Debugging and Profiling). I don't know which ones might help, since I can't reproduce the problem, but you could try --log-level=3.

@ekhumoro Thanks very much , it works ! see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78801496/1485853

There are two ways to stop the logging,
os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--log-level=3"

or
sys.argv.extend(['--webEngineArgs',"--log-level=3"])

